# How do I resolve the "Cannot assign 'String' to 'Publication'" Gradle errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, ide, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Gradle 6.7 for a project and I'm using IntelliJ. When writing Gradle files or when running inspections, I keep getting this error.

> "Cannot assign 'String' to 'Publication'".

Based on the Gradle docs and all the examples, it seems as though my configuration is correct but I'm unable to resolve these warnings.

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

buildscript {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.github.ngbinh.scalastyle:gradle-scalastyle-plugin_2.11:1.0.1"
            classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.8"
            classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-nullaway-plugin:0.2"
            classpath "gradle.plugin.com.dorongold.plugins:task-tree:1.5"
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scalaStyle'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.errorprone'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.nullaway'
apply plugin: "com.dorongold.task-tree"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

group 'com.mridang'
version '0.0.2'

...
...

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "github"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/mridang/myrepo")
            credentials(PasswordCredentials)
        }
    }
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact scaladocJar

            pom {
                name = 'myproject'
                description = 'Foo'
                url = 'https://github.com/mridang/myrepo'
                issueManagement {
                    system = "Github"
                    url = "https://github.com/mridang/myrepo/issues"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot that better illustrates the issue:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: is this an error you get from running gradle on commandline/terminal?  Or is just intellij complaining?

Comment: This is just Intellij 2020.1 complaining

Comment: Welcome to the world of "intellij has no clue what is going on" ;)

Answer (score 7):

It is false positive inspection warning. You can vote for this issue in tracker: [IDEA-162281](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162281).